# Anypoint Studio taking too long Validating project after every change in XML or java

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Anypoint Studio taking too long Validating project after every change in XML or java. Here is the snapshot showing the problem. This is very annoying ... how can I disable validation and make it work faster.

[image: Mule Anypoint Studio validation problem]

Answer (score 3):

> how can I disable validation and make it work faster.

option you are looking for is called **Turn off error reporting in XML editor**. It is a checkbox located under **Anypoint Studio** menu in Preferences.

[image]

keep in mind that you wont get the "Flow name should be unique" warning anymore. some other feature may stop working too.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide additional information as to

- Operating System
- Amount of Memory
- CPU type and speed
- Anypoint Studio Version
- Java Version being used with Anypoint Studio

To turn off validations
 Anypoint Studio Preferences -> Anypoint Studio

You will see a list of validation options

Answer (score 0):

You can increase configurations values such as **Xms1024m, Xmx2048m, MaxPermSize=1024m** in **"AnypointStudio.ini"** file in the AnypointStudio installation directory which will make AnypointStudio work comparatively smooth.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable validation from preferences.

1. Go to: Windows--> Preferences--> Validation
2. Select check-box "Suspend all validators"
3. Click on apply.

It should work.

Comment: Tried suspending the validators ... problem persists.